# Check if string has a letter followed by a number before a dash

Tags: jquery, regex

So, i want to check if a string (which is the current pathname) has the letter "p" followed by one (or two) numbers and it is before the first dash. Like this:

Does not match:

> /t20-some-title-here

Match:

> /t20p30-some-title-here
>
> /t20p2-some-title-here
>
> /t20p50-some-title-here

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this on your own first?

Comment: @hwnd Yep. I'm kinda new to JQuery/Javascript. I know that i can use the _.match_ method and use Regex, but i cannot figure out how to filter all the things at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/[^-]*p[0-9]{1,2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/xT6bU5/1

You could use it as follows:

```
var res = yourstring.match(/
/\/[^-]*p[0-9]{1,2}/g);
```

The variable res will be an array with all matches.

Comment: PS: If you want the regex to match the complete path, use this one instead: \/[^-]*p[0-9]{1,2}.*